# $\liminf _{n\to\infty}(u_n+v_n)$ when just $u_n$ is known to converge?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Does anyone know if there exists a simple relation between $\liminf_{n\to\infty} (u_n+v_n)$ and $\liminf u_n + \liminf v_n$ when let say $u_n$ converges?

Comment: If $u_n$ is convergent to $u$ then $liminf(u_n + v_n)=u+liminfv_n$. try a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we only have $\liminf(u_n+v_n)\ge \liminf u_n+\liminf v_n$.
But if $\lim u_n=u$ then $\liminf (u_n+v_n)=u+\liminf v_n$.